# Of the root permission for postgres

Tags: linux, postgresql, nginx

I have an application in rails, with nginx and possenger,
Running in root .
But the application does not connect to postgres. In root ....
All my connections work except root.
I assume that it is root permission to access postgres ...

Can someone help me?

Comment: you provided postgresql connection strings correctly>??
add more explanation to the question with nginx conf or other config details in the server !

Comment: I recommend you to check all processes how they really run. Because for example nginx master process runs as root but worker processes can run under some different user like nginx or www-data etc. So you may actually have problem that some specific user is unable to connect to postgresql. Check in pg_hba.conf if you allow locally all users to connect or only some.